# Windows Runtime Component: Variable for the UWP Image element and how to get it from XAML

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

Suppose that I have a UWP app where in MainPage.xaml, what I have is an image control (or image pane) as an instance of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image (called testImage), and I have a Windows Runtime component in C++. MainPage.xaml also has a button and a button listener to run a function in the component to change the image control's source.

Using code for the Windows Runtime component, how do I get that element that's already defined in the XAML file to change its source to a WriteableBitmap instance (holding an image) and display it in the image control? In this case, the image control is put in place by using the Visual Studio 2017 XAML Designer.

Using this line

```
auto testImage = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Image();
```

only instantiates a new image control to be placed in MainPage.xaml itself, even when the variable name matches the value of the Name attribute for the image control as an XAML element.

I do remember seeing the documentation and I think one StackOverflow question where it is possible to reference an XAML element between a script and a UWP app page, but that's in C#. Here, I want it in C++ because I am using OpenCV.

EDIT: Hmm, perhaps one alternative would be to have the component simply process the image using OpenCV, pass it back to the button listener in C#, then set the source attribute of that image control to the processed image.

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. If you give a XAML Image element the name like `x:Name="testImage"`, you should be able to access it from the code-behind of that page.

Comment: Your edit seems reasonable. But I am not clear about your question too. Please keep in mind that the recommend way to handle changes is to deal with data. Like MVVM technology, we are always changing the data and which will cause the UI to refresh.

Comment: @MartinZikmund - I am not quite familiar with the x: prefix.

From doing some more research on Friday, I learned that usually, data binding is involved between the UWP widget and a data model underneath written in C#, which is then related using C++ through a DLL import, I think.

I think what I am trying to do is change the source of the image that's binded to my image control to an image that's been processed by OpenCV function calls. So far, the only way I found is by using a WriteableBitmap instance and a conversion method.